# Sometimes the list connects other times it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes the lists connect and you can transfer between them.  Other times it doesn't connect.  At all times you can sort within each list, but sometimes not between them.  I can't figure it out.

```
$('#questions .survey-page ul').sortable({
  items: 'li:not(.placeholder)',
  sort: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-edit'); // While sorting we do not want edit buttons to show.
  },
  update: function() {
    refreshAllDetails(); // Update survey with the new details.
  },
  connectWith: '#questions .survey-page ul'
});
```

`#question` is a tag that multiple `.survey-page` children are put into.  Each `.survey-page` has a `ul` with multiple `li` entries.  It is this `ul` that I am trying to link between `.survey-page`s.

EDIT: As per request:

```js
/**
     * Saves the order of questions, then saves the details of all questions to server.
     */
    function refreshAllDetails() {
     saveOrder();
     saveAllToDatabase();
    }
    
    /**
     * Saves the details of all questions to server.
     */
    function saveAllToDatabase() {
     // Go through each page.
     $("#questions").find(".survey-page").each(function() {
      var surveypage = this;
      // Save metadata for current page.  
      // Go through each question on page.
      $(this).find(".questiontypestuffp").each(function() {
       
       // Get the answers for a particular question, including meta-data for question.
       var result = callWidget($(this), "getEditedAnswers");
       
       // Get the order of the question listed on page.
       result.questionorder = $(this).attr('ordervalue');
       result.pageno = $(surveypage).attr("ordervalue");
       
       // Save the question's order to its associated widget.
             callWidget($(this), "setData", result);
                          
             // Update the question in database.
             $.ajax({dataType: "json", url: "index.php?option=com_survey&loadorsave=update&view=surveydata&layout=edit&id=" + $("#itemid").val() + "&tmpl=component&format=json&questionvalues=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(result)), success: function(callback) {
           
          }});
             
             // Turn off edit mode.
                setEditModeOff();
       
      });
      
     });
    }
    
    /**
     * Refreshes order values with regard to their position on page.  This rewrites the order values as they appear.
     */
    function saveOrder() {
     
     var pageorder = 0;
     
     // GO through each page.
     $("#questions").find(".survey-page").each(function() {
      var questionorder = 0;
      
      // Rewrite page order.
      var currentPage = ++pageorder;
      $(this).attr('ordervalue', currentPage);
      
      // Rewrite each question's order on page.
      $(this).find(".questiontypestuffp").each(function() {
          $(this).attr('ordervalue', ++questionorder);
         });
      
     });
     
    }
```

Comment: *«sometimes»* and *«other times»* is not really instructive on the test cases... Try to have a working example with exactly defined step to reproduce.

Comment: Make sure you are using `$(document).ready(......)` or something similar to delay running your code until all of the page has finished loading.

Comment: What i meant by <sometimes> and <othertimes> is that whether it will work or not is entirely random.  And yes the code is delayed from running via $(document).ready(), and events from user input.  I'll try and get a jsfiddle onto it

Comment: Would it be possible that `refreshAllDetails()` dynamically adds `<ul>` elements? Show that function for fun... ;)

Comment: ok - I'm showing the function in an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own problem here.  The class I was removing was actually required to recognize drag and drop operations, hence 'ui-state-edit'.  By dynamically updating this class to/from the DOM element, this was affecting whether the list item was able to be transferred between lists.  As a brief - drag and drop was rejecting the list item since it didn't have a valid class name.